# How to flatten a Map by turning its values into keys

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

How can I transform a `Map<String, List<String>>` into flattened map based on values grouped as keys.

I.e. from `Map<String, List<String>>` to `Map<String, String>` (flattened by values)

For an example.

**Source map:**

```
<"fuel", ["BMW", "Honda"]>,
<"electric", ["Tesla", "Nio"]>
```

**Flattened map:**

```
[  
"BMW" : "fuel",  
"Honda" : "fuel",  
"Tesla" : "electric",  
"Nio" : "electric"
]
```

Comment: Now imagine you have your `Map<String, String>`. What should be result of `yourMap.get("fuel")`? Should it be `"BMW"` `"Honda"` OR maybe *both* grouped, like `["BMW", "Honda"]` (like you had originally...)?

Comment: I should have rephrased my question in a better way. My intention was to create a name value pair out of the map which contains value as a list of string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have **multiple keys** identical according to `equals/hashCode` within the same map because it contradicts with idea of the **map** data structure. Every key must be unique, you can't store multiple entries with the **same key** in a `Map`.

But you can create a **list** of `Map.Entry` objects.

For that, you need to create a stream over the *entry set* and then **flatten** each entry by creating a **new entry** based on car brands (elements of a *flatted value*) for each *key*:

```
        Map<String, List<String>> cars =
                Map.of("fuel", List.of("BMW", "Honda"),
                        "electric", List.of("Tesla", "Nio"));

        List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries =
                cars.entrySet().stream()
                    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                                .map(brand -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(), brand)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(entries);
```

**output**

```
[electric=Tesla, electric=Nio, fuel=BMW, fuel=Honda]
```

---

Or maybe your intention was to create a `Map<String, String>` that will allow to retrieve *car type* based on *brand* (like that: *"BMW" : "fuel", "Honda" : "fuel"*) then it'll make sense.

The overall approach will be similar to the previous one:

- create a stream over the *entry set*;
- *flatten* each entry using `flatMap()` by turning an element in the value-list into a **new entry**;
- collect elements to a *map* with `Collectors.toMap()`.

But there's a **caveat**: all values have to be unique or there must be a rule on how to *combine/discarde* car types.

I'll make an assumption that all brands in the map are unique, otherwise, the code below will fail (*to deal with collisions* `Collectors.toMap()` *requires the third argument* - `mergeFunction`).

```
        Map<String, String> typeByBrand =
                cars.entrySet().stream()
                        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                                .map(brand -> Map.entry(brand, entry.getKey())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                  Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(typeByBrand);
```

**output**

```
{Nio=electric, Tesla=electric, BMW=fuel, Honda=fuel}
```